# How to concatenate different row collections with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have several `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` objects which contain many columns, and I want to concatenate them in a LINQ expression. The row collections do not have exactly same columns, but the first two are same type.

Simplified situation:

```
Rows1 columns:
Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |

Rows2 columns:
Col1  |  Col2  |  Col4  |

Rows3 columns:
Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |  Col5  |
```

I want the result row collection to contain `Col1` and `Col2` from collections `Rows1`, `Rows2` and `Rows3`:

```
from Rows1: |  Col1  |  Col2  |
from Rows2: |  Col1  |  Col2  |
from Rowd3: |  Col1  |  Col2  |
```

As mentioned, `Col1` and `Col2` are same type.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could'nt you just select col1 & col 2 from every RowCollection and then add the results to your target list if everything else is non-relevant?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Rows1.Col1`, `Rows2.Col1` and `Rows3.Col1` are the same Type:

```
var res = Rows1
    .Select(p=> p.Col1)
    .Concat(Rows2.Select(o=> o.Col1))
    .Concat(Rows3.Select(o=> o.Col1))
```

(Just add Col2 in the same manner)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you're looking for something like:

```
var result = rows.Aggregate((temp, next) => temp.Intersect(next));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersect maybe:

```
foreach(row in Rows) // Rows include row1,row2 and row3
{
  result = Rows[0].Intersect(row); // Rows[0] equal row1
}
```

Note: I couldnt try it, i hope this help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this way ?

```
Public class RowColumns {
  public string Col1 { get;set; }
  public string Col2 { get;set; }
}
```

Your collection-

```
var collection= dbContext.Table.ToList();
```

selection columns -

```
using System.Linq;

var result = collection.select(c=> new RowColumns {
   Col1 = c.Col1,
   Col2 = c.Col2
});
```